# More than one storage class Specified

Tags: c++, dictionary, unordered

I was trying to create two different methods for storing data at the beginning before int main. I had an unordered map and just a regular map. I got the error, more than one storage class specified..

I was just wondering why C++ doesn't allow that?

```
typedef struct dictionary{ 
 std::string word; 
unsigned char hash[20]; 

 std::string hex;
 int number;
 } a_dictionary;


 typedef struct brute{
int entry;
string secWord;
string secHex;
}

typedef std::unordered_map<std::string, dictionary*> Mymap;
typedef std::map<int, brute*> Solved;
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
string option;
string pass;
int choice=0;

Solved solution;
Mymap c1;
```

error C2159: more than one storage class specified
 error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'Mymap'
 error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
 error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'c1'
 error C2065: 'c1' : undeclared identifier

error C2159: more than one storage class specified

Comment: Please show the C++ code, and copy-paste the exact error message from your compiler.

Comment: i've put the c++ code @dasblinkenlight

Comment: Does it give you a line number for the error? What line of code does it correspond to?

Comment: i haved added the two structs that i have at the beginning of the code @GrigoriyChudnov

Comment: You're missing a `;` at the end of the definition of `struct brute`. Copy/paste error?

Comment: Yes. You also don't need `typedef` in front of `struct`. In fact you really should not use `typedef` there (some compiles ignore it, others will be confused).